# The most efficient way to returning today's documents from a collection

Tags: mongodb, datetime, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-aggregation

I have a collection where all the documents in that collection have a datetime timestamp that includes the time as well as the date.

When using the aggregation framework how do I say give me the values for today? The following only gives me the entries for midnight.

```
db.strategy.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $match: {
             "date": new Date()
            }
        },

    ]
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the documents which have datetime values for today, you need to create a date query range where the `start` date object should hold the current date time hours at `00:00:00.000` (milliseconds precision) and set the hours for today's date to `23:59:59.999` to the `end` date variable.

For example:

```
// Create the start date which holds the beginning of today
var todayStart = new Date();
todayStart.setHours(0,0,0,0);

// Create the end date which holds the end of today
var todayEnd = new Date();
todayEnd.setHours(23,59,59,999);

// Create the date range query object
var query = {
    "date": {
        $gte: todayStart,
        $lte: todayEnd
    }
};

// using the find() method
db.strategy.find(query);
```

Or using the `aggregate()` method as

```
db.strategy.aggregate({ "$match": query });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess what I was checking by my question is that I can't apply the date methods to the value in the database and then get a simple date1=date2 comparison.

Comment: No worries :) That would be an equality comparison which won't apply in your case since you are comparing a value within a given range.

Comment: I guess that is my point. I want the equality check thisDate = date() and not thisDateTime between today.setHours(0,0,0,0) and today.setHours(23,59,59,999). To do that the former I would need to be able to truncate the stored date to remove the time.

Answer (score 0):

You should get the value in range I.e. from today's 12AM time stamp  to today's 23:59:59 timestamp.

Var d = new Date();
     var startDate = d.setHours(0,0,0);
      var endDate = d.setHours(23,59, 59);
    db.strategy.aggregate(
      [
          {
               $match: {
                       "date": {$gte: startDate, $lte: endDate}
                }
            },

```
   ]
);
```